# How to set dex memory limit from command line?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been running into a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20340498/3342206), specifically, a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` when gradle runs dex. The solution seems to be to add this to the build.gradle:

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize = "4g" // this line specifically
    }
}
```

Now, assume, for reasons, that I cannot modify build.gradle, or anything at all in the project folder as such changes or additions would be wiped out next time the project is pulled from the repository. How can I set the `javaMaxHeapSize` for dex through a command line option or an environment variable or some such method that can be easily automated?

I've tried using the `-P` flag, like this: `gradle -Pandroid.dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize=3g printProps` with this build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
}

task printProps {
    println "android.dexOptions: " + android.dexOptions.getJavaMaxHeapSize()
}
```

Unfortunately, it only prints out `android.dexOptions: null` (before failing because I haven't set up a complete Android project for this little test). The `printProps` task seems to print the correct method, as when I alter the build.gradle to set the `javaMaxHeapSize`, it prints out the correct value.

Comment: Clone the existing `build.gradle` into `build-8bittree.gradle`. Adjust `javaMaxHeapSize` in the clone. Use `gradle -b build-8bittree.gradle` to build with your custom `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @CommonsWare Not a bad suggestion. Unfortunately it reminded me of something I originally forgot to mention, specifically that I want to be able to easily automate it. Creating it once and storing it outside the project directory runs the risk of `build-8bittree.gradle` becoming outdated. Setting things up to reliably recreate it each time sounds like more work than this all should be. Still, make that an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Using your favorite scripting environment, copy `build.gradle` to `build-8bittree.gradle`

Step #2: Using your favorite scripting environment, append the following to `build-8bittree.gradle`:

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize = "4g" // this line specifically
    }
}
```

(you are not limited to a single `android` closure, so the fact that there probably already is an `android` closure is not a limiting factor)

Step #3: Using your favorite scripting environment, use the `-b` switch to have `gradle` build with your custom `build-8bittree.gradle` file